# ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar el FloatingActionButton dependiendo del Scroll?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un botón circular flotante `FloatingActionButton` en una vista con un `recyclerview`, necesito coordinar el `scroll` del `recyclerview` con la visibilidad de `FloatingActionButton`:

- Se oculte cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo
- Se muestre cuando se hace scroll hacia arriba

Imagen de muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se debe englobar en un `CoordinatorLayout` ejemplo de la jerarquia:

```
CoordinatorLayout
   AppBarLayout
      Toolbar
   RecyclerView
   FloatingActionButton
```

Para interceptar el scroll

```
public class FabScrollBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FabScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }
}
```

y en el `FloatingActionButton` donde queremos interceptar que se haga scroll en el recycleview

```
...
app:layout_behavior="tu.pcakage.android.FabScrollBehavior"
...
```

Tutorial [Hide the FloatingActionButton when scrolling a RecyclerView](http://androidessence.com/hide-the-floatingactionbutton-when-scrolling-a-recyclerview/)