# Animar Floating Action Button (slide up,down) dependiendo del Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout

En este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10715/c%C3%B3mo-ocultar-y-mostrar-el-floatingactionbutton-dependiendo-del-scroll) hay la solución para ocular y mostrar el *fab button* `FloatingActionButton` dependiendo del scroll

Pero me gustaría que cuando se oculte y mostrase el *fab button*  lo hiciera con una animación slide Arriba y Abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas, utilizando una clase que extienda de `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` y enlazándolo con la view del `Floating Action Button` en el `XML` o programandolo directamente en el `RecyclerView`.

Te voy a enseñar las dos formas y tu eliges la que más te guste.

**PRIMER MÉTODO**

Cuando busqué como hacer justo lo que tu estas preguntando, todo lo que aparecía utilizaban el mismo método. Creaban una nueva clase java y extendían de `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` para detectar el movimiento de la `ListView` o `RecyclerView` (lo que utilices) y luego enlazan esta misma clase con el view del `Floating Action Button` (`FAB`) de la siguiente forma:

Clase `FABMove.java`:

```
public class FABMove extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FABMove(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            int margin = layoutParams.bottomMargin;
            child.animate().translationY(child.getHeight() + margin).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000).start();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
            child.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }
}
```

Y ahora, solo tienes que ir al archivo `XML` donde tengas declarado el `FAB` y añadir un `CoordinatorLayout` encapsulando tu `RecyclerView` y el `FAB` y a este le añades la propiedad `app:layout_behavior` que enlaza con tu clase java:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent">  

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>  

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_margin="16dp" 
      app:layout_anchor="@+id/recycler_view" 
      app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" 
      app:layout_behavior="com.victoria.fabsmove.FABMove" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Listo!

**SEGUNDO MÉTODO:**

Este método, para mi, lo veo relativamente sencillo, mucho más que el primero porque no se tiene que crear tantas cosa. Simplemente tienes que agregar la función `addOnScrollListener()` al `RecyclerView` y sobrescribir el método `onScrolled()` para que detecte el movimiento de la lista.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
            if (dy > 0)
                // Puedes ocultarlo simplemente
                //fab.hide();
                // o añadir la animación deseada
                fab.animate().translationY(fab.getHeight() +
                            getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin))
                            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                            .setDuration(1000); // Cambiar al tiempo deseado
            else if (dy < 0)
                //fab.show();
                 fab.animate().translationY(0)
                            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                            .setDuration(1000); // Cambiar al tiempo deseado

        }
    });
```

Con esto ya estaría todo listo. Si tienes alguna duda avisa enseguida.

Aún así, la respuesta que ha dado nuestro compañero Andres Gillermo Castellanos A ([link](https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/)), porque además te enseñas a crear menús directamente en el `FAB` y es muy interesante.

Mucha suerte con tu app!!

Comment: gracias, he adaptado un poco el código a mi app, funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Compañero, en este sitio https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/ encontrara la respuesta paso a paso y ademas puede descargar el ejemplo que se encuentra en este git https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/FloatingActionButton_Animation_Project

Espero haberle ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución usando `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` adaptando el código de la respuesta @Vicky_Vicent

Añado un `flag` para saber si la animación está en curso, para evitar sobrecarga de animación.

```
public class AboutFabScrollBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    private boolean startAnimation = false;

    public AboutFabScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled down and the FAB is currently visible -> hide the FAB
            if (!startAnimation) {
                Interpolator interpolador = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    interpolador = AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                            android.R.interpolator.fast_out_linear_in);
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                    child.animate()
                            //.translationYBy(0f)
                            .translationY(child.getHeight() +
                                    child.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin))
                            .setInterpolator(interpolador)
                            .setDuration(child.getContext().getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime))
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                    child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    startAnimation = false;
                                }
                            })
                            .start();
                }
                startAnimation = true;
            }


        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            // User scrolled up and the FAB is currently not visible -> show the FAB
            if (!startAnimation) {
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Interpolator interpolador = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    interpolador = AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                            android.R.interpolator.fast_out_linear_in);
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    child.animate()
//                            .translationYBy(150f)
                            .translationY(0f)
                            .setInterpolator(interpolador)
                            .setDuration(child.getContext().getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime))
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                    startAnimation = false;
                                }
                            })
                            .start();
                }


                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_in);
                child.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        //return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }
}
```